# Meteorite router package installation - Uncaught 'error' event on 'mrt add router'

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteorite

I get the following exception/error upon `mrt add router` :-

`events.js:74
        throw TypeError('Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.');
              ^
TypeError: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.
    at TypeError (<anonymous>)
    at WebSocket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:74:15)
    at Receiver.self._receiver.onerror (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:566:10)
    at Receiver.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:301:8)
    at Receiver.processPacket (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:215:43)
    at Receiver.add (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:93:24)
    at CleartextStream.firstHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:524:22)
    at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at CleartextStream.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:736:14)
    at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)`

Meteor version: `0.6.3.1`. Meteorite version: `0.4.6`. Node version: `0.10.9`.

I'm not sure what is wrong where. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Node 0.10.9 has a couple of issues. I'm not sure it'll help but try `mrt add router --repoPort=80` as suggested here : https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/issues/135

Comment: I just tried, and there is no response, no error, nothing. The package isn't getting installed as well.